# How to schedule Jenkins build in pipeline script with custom parameters

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job with several parameters, each with default value, for example:

```
SUITE_NAME: business/common.xml     
BROWSER_NAME: ff
```

I need the job to be started 2 times by cron, with different input parameters, like:

1st launch: 5AM

```
SUITE_NAME: business/common.xml
BROWSER_NAME: ff
```

2st launch: 7AM

```
SUITE_NAME: events/some-other.xml
BROWSER_NAME: ff
```

So `SUITE_NAME` and probably some other parameters could vary. 
How can I set this in the pipeline scrip of in job settings via Jenkins interface?

The only solution I see now is to trigger the build each hour, get current time, and change the value of `SUITE_NAME` depending on whether it's 5AM or 7AM but this really looks weird.

thanks in advance.

Comment: why not two separate pipelines (cron 5AM for one and 7AM for the other) triggering the target job with different parameters?

Comment: because conceptually it is the same parameterized build and I do not want to clone other settings.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using this answer and plugin:

[add build parameter in jenkins build schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594703/add-build-parameter-in-jenkins-build-schedule/34599662#34599662)

https://github.com/jwmach1/parameterized-scheduler

```
00 05 * * 1-5 %SUITE_NAME=business/common.xml
05 05 * * 1-5 %SUITE_NAME=events/some-other.xml
```

etc...