# How to add ExtendedChoiceParameter in Jenkins build schedule?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I know how to add StringParameter in Jenkins build schedule with [parameterized-scheduler-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin), the right answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594703/add-build-parameter-in-jenkins-build-schedule)

However my problem is when I add

```bash
H/5 * * * * % release_version=2.15.0.0;base_version=master;Process_start=CodeScan,CodeCompiler;release_env_st=TEST
```

in *Build periodically with parameters*, the parameter `Process_start` was not recogonized, other StringParameter was fine.

[image: jenkins_build_with_parameter]
<sub>(source: [aliyuncs.com](https://liaogx-public-img.oss-cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/devops/jenkins_build_with_parameter.png))</sub>

Here is the parameter definition in Restful API result when Jenkins build, you can see the parameter `Process_part` is an *ExtendedChoiceParameter* type

```json
        {
            "_class": "hudson.model.ParametersAction",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "_class": "hudson.model.StringParameterValue",
                    "name": "release_version",
                    "value": "2.15.0.0"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "hudson.model.StringParameterValue",
                    "name": "base_version",
                    "value": "master"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterValue",
                    "name": "Process_part",
                    "value": "CodeScan,CodeComplier,CodeCompare,PackageRelease,ArtifactManage"
                },
                {
                    "_class": "hudson.model.StringParameterValue",
                    "name": "release_env_st",
                    "value": "TEST"
                }
            ]
        },
```

So how should I do to add ExtendedChoiceParameter in periodically build? Help me please!